# Anti-System time cheat not fully working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, systemtime

**Whats Happening:**
It works for the most part except after some time after using the offline coin count is always 0. Im am trying to make it so the player cant just change their system time to try to get more money faster. I also am not trying to do this by connection to server for time check. Does anyone see whats going wrong?

**If statement is in awake:**

```
if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("offlineCheck").Equals(1))
        {
            ButtonCanvas.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            OfflineCanvas.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("offlineCheck", 0);
            // year not the same
            if (!PlayerPrefs.GetInt("year").Equals(System.DateTime.Now.Year))
            {
                // Add 24 Hour Coins
                if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("year") < System.DateTime.Now.Year)
                {
                    offlineCoinCount = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("OfflineCoinsVal") * (24 * 60);
                } else {
                    offlineCoinCount = 0;
                }
            }
            else
            { // same Year
              // month not the same
                if (!PlayerPrefs.GetInt("month").Equals(System.DateTime.Now.Month))
                {
                    // Add 24 Hour Coins
                    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("month") < System.DateTime.Now.Month)
                    {
                        offlineCoinCount = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("OfflineCoinsVal") * (24 * 60);
                    } else {
                        offlineCoinCount = 0;
                    }
                }
                else
                { // Same Month
                  // day not the same
                    if (!PlayerPrefs.GetInt("day").Equals(System.DateTime.Now.Day))
                    {
                        // Add 24 hours?
                        if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("day") < System.DateTime.Now.Day)
                        {
                            offlineCoinCount = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("OfflineCoinsVal") * (24 * 60);
                        } else {
                            offlineCoinCount = 0;
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    { // Same Day
                      // hour not the same
                        if (!PlayerPrefs.GetInt("timeHour").Equals(System.DateTime.Now.Hour))
                        {
                            // Add Coins
                            if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("timeHour") < System.DateTime.Now.Hour)
                            {
                                offlineCoinCount = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("OfflineCoinsVal") * (((System.DateTime.Now.Hour - PlayerPrefs.GetInt("timeHour")) * 60) - (System.DateTime.Now.Minute - PlayerPrefs.GetInt("timeMin")));
                            } else {
                                offlineCoinCount = 0;
                            }

                        }
                        else
                        { // Same hour
                          // min not the same
                            if (!PlayerPrefs.GetInt("timeMin").Equals(System.DateTime.Now.Minute))
                            {
                                // Add coins
                                offlineCoinCount = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("OfflineCoinsVal") * (System.DateTime.Now.Minute - PlayerPrefs.GetInt("timeMin"));

                            }
                            else
                            { // Same min

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

**Rest of Code for this anti-time cheat**

```
private void OnApplicationQuit()
{
    saveDateTime();
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("offlineCheck", 1);
    //offlineCoinCount = 0;
}


private void OnApplicationFocus(bool focus)
{
    saveDateTime();
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("offlineCheck", 1);
    //offlineCoinCount = 0;
}
private void OnApplicationPause(bool pause)
{
    saveDateTime();
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("offlineCheck", 1);
    //offlineCoinCount = 0;
}
public void saveDateTime()
{
    //Player Restart Game
    //////
    /// Check Time for coin bonus
    ////

    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("year").Equals(System.DateTime.Now.Year))
    { // Same Year
        if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("month").Equals(System.DateTime.Now.Month))
        { // Same Month
            if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("day").Equals(System.DateTime.Now.Day))
            { // Same Day
                if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("timeHour").Equals(System.DateTime.Now.Hour))
                { // Same Hour
                    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("timeMin").Equals(System.DateTime.Now.Minute))
                    { // Same Minute

                    }
                    else
                    { // Different Minute
                        // Update if new Minute is higher than old
                        if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("timeMin") < System.DateTime.Now.Month)
                        {
                            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("timeMin", System.DateTime.Now.Minute);
                        }
                    }

                }
                else
                { //Different Hour
                    // Update if new hour is higher than old
                    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("timeHour") < System.DateTime.Now.Month)
                        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("timeHour", System.DateTime.Now.Hour);
                    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("timeMin", System.DateTime.Now.Minute);
                }
            }
            else
            { // Different Day
              // Update if new day is higher than old
                if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("day") < System.DateTime.Now.Month)
                {
                    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("day", System.DateTime.Now.Year);
                    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("timeHour", System.DateTime.Now.Hour);
                    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("timeMin", System.DateTime.Now.Minute);
                }
            }

        }
        else
        { // Different Month

            // Update if new month is higher than old
            if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("month") < System.DateTime.Now.Month)
            {
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("month", System.DateTime.Now.Year);
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("day", System.DateTime.Now.Year);
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("timeHour", System.DateTime.Now.Hour);
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("timeMin", System.DateTime.Now.Minute);
            }
        }
    }

    else
    { // Different Year
        // Update if new year is higher than old
        if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("year") < System.DateTime.Now.Year)
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("year", System.DateTime.Now.Year);
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("month", System.DateTime.Now.Year);
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("day", System.DateTime.Now.Year);
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("timeHour", System.DateTime.Now.Hour);
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("timeMin", System.DateTime.Now.Minute);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd start by adding some logging to determine which of the conditions is setting the count to 0. Also, I'd start using UTC instead of the local time - at the moment you'll think that a player is cheating if they happen to run the code around a "fall back" daylight saving transition.

Comment: I would write the time the user exits the application. On the next app launch, the current time only needs to be later than that, or the app won't start. The user can start exploiting the time but it will get inconvenient very fast: update time, launch app, close app, revert time, etc.

Comment: **[1]** On several places your program stores *year* to *day* (e.g. `PlayerPrefs.SetInt("day", System.DateTime.Now.Year);`) . I do not know what your intention is, but such code really smells. **[2]** If code like `PlayerPrefs.SetInt("timeHour", System.DateTime.Now.Hour); PlayerPrefs.SetInt("timeMin", System.DateTime.Now.Minute);` executes just before start of new hour (for example at 5:59:59), it could happen that *timeHour* will be set to 5 and *timeMin* to 0 (instead of 59) because hour changes meanwhile.